# exit button .swf file

Tags: actionscript-2, exit

I've been into forums and other sites that have answered this question. They've given this code:

```
on(release) {
fscommand("quit");
}
```

but it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting it on a different layer. put something on the layer like a transparent box, or else the frame will be ignored.

Comment: leave the background where it is just move the button to the last frame on a new layer.

Comment: if it's on the last frame it will only shoe at the end. if you want it to show all the way through put it at the beginning and put a tween all the way to the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
on(press)
{fscommand("quit","true");
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to explain why your answer is correct, not just post code by itself.